# Как сделать переключатель по кнопке

Tags: php

Есть кнопка `<a class="hv linkphoto button8">Логин</a>`
Как сделать переключатель по кнопке, чтобы при нажатии `$num` менялся на число 99? Просто делаю сайт и нужно просто кнопку на php сделать, ничего более, остальное шаблон

Comment: Кнопки обычно на html+js+css делаются. Плюс у вас не кнопка, а ссылка. Делайте на html переключатель и передавайте с помощью js запрос на php...и на php реализуете серверную логику

Comment: -_- почти понял

Comment: Держите себя в руках, к вашему сведению php - язык на котором в основном реализуют серверную логику

Comment: неужели нельзя сделать что-то типо if button = (clicked) {$num = 99}

Comment: Код покажите свой....видимо у вас идет все подряд, раз вы думаете что та можно

Comment: это не важно. просто нужен код кнопки для сайта, которое переключает значение $num на 99, что непонятного??

Comment: Учитесь разговаривать сначала в соответствии с правилами этикета, и потом, возможно вам помогут.

Comment: И ещё у вас нет кода, который бы вы попытались сделать....

Comment: Какой код вам нужен? Сколько мне еще повторить, что код не важен и ни на что не влияет, нужно просто  присвоить значение $num по нажатию на кнопку...

Comment: Используйте `GET` для перехода по адресным ссылкам. Советую сразу смотреть в сторону `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'address')`.

Answer (score 0):

Клиент:

```
<a href="?num=99" class="hv linkphoto button8">Логин</a>
```

Сервер:

```
$num = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'num', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```